# Unable to reclaim reserved blocks for root on EXT4 external HDD

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, external-hdd, ext4

I am trying to reclaim the reserved blocks for root on a 2TB external HDD connected via USB using EXT4 fs. The blocks amounts to ~93GB which I'd very much like to reclaim and use. It is mounted on `/media/2tb` as `/dev/sdb1`.

I am attempting to do this with the `tune2fs` utility, as such:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdb1
tune2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 0% (0 blocks)
```

The above contains the full output of `tune2fs`, there are no errors whatsoever.

Checking to see if the blocks has been reclaimed with the same utility:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep 'Reserved block count'
Reserved block count:     24418892
```

As you can see nothing changes, the block count stay the same as before I ran the utility. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and `1.42.13` is the latest version for Ubuntu 14.04 of `e2fsprogs` where the `tune2fs` utility comes from. From what I've read, it isn't required to unmount the drive or perform a reboot, but I still tried it to no avail.

Comment: 24418892 blocks is about 11.6GB, give or take, which is about 0.6% of 2TB. I don't know why zero doesn't work. Have you tried to experiment with different numbers, for example 0.5 or 0.1?

Comment: Did you unmount the volume before running `tune2fs`?

Comment: @mikewhatever That's odd, I use netdata to monitor the instance and it reports 93GB reserved for root, [see this picture](https://i.imgur.com/9uJviBV.png). The reported block size is 4KB though which does amount to 93GB when multiplied with reserved block count. And yes, I have tried with different numbers to no avail, the reserved block count stays at `24418892`. @psusi yes I have unmounted the volume before running `tune2fs`, as written in the original question.

Comment: Maybe try -r 0 to set the number of reserved blocks to 0.

Comment: @ubfan1 Tried that right now to no avail, unmounted the volume first too. The weird part is that I'm not getting any errors or messages whatsoever, but the process quits with exit code `1` when checking `echo $?` after running the command.

Comment: How much free space is on the drive? Maybe the reserve is already in use.

Comment: @ubfan1 Around 10% free, roughly 184GB. If that's the case, how do I reclaim that space?

Comment: Some parameter changes require an e2fsck afterwards, but the reserve blocks are not documented to be among them.  Did you try a reboot after a change -- maybe there is a cache with the old number in it.  Also try the -r with a low number not zero, like 1 to see if that "takes".

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "reclaim the reserved blocks for root". Are you trying to allocate that space to another partition? What about the data that's there... not required any more to boot? Show me a screenshot of `gparted` and I'll take a look for you. Ping me at `@heynnema`.

Comment: @heynnema I realize now that I should've mentioned it, but this drive is not the drive that I have installed the OS on. This is just an external HDD that I use to archive personal files (photos, videos, repositories, etc) for long-term storage. From what I've read, blocks reserved for the root user in EXT4 is meant to deal with fragmentation, but since the data on the disk is rarely changed and that EXT4 is better at handling fragmentation than its previous versions (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7965)) I'd rather be able to use those blocks myself (93GB after all).